Does wiring in a pole building need to be in conduit?
I'm going to wire my 24' x 24' detached pole garage in Geauga Co. OH. Can I run Romex everywhere ? Or do I need to run wiring in conduit.

You are going to need either conduit + wires or direct-bury cable between the main building and the garage.
But the inside of the garage depends on local code. I searched the county web site and could not find an answer - the only electrical thing I found was a permit. You need to check with them - contact details on https://bocc.geauga.oh.gov/departments/building-department - and ask them (a) what NEC code year they use, (b) what exceptions/amendments do they have to the standard NEC code, (c) what is a homeowner allowed to do.
Most places (but not all) allow a homeowner to make minor repairs and changes inside their home without special training or a permit. But a new building? That will almost certainly require permits and inspections no matter who does the work. Depending on the jurisdiction, that could be any of:

All work must be done by a licensed electrician
Certain work (e.g., panel installation) must be done by a licensed electrician but other work can be done by the homeowner
All work can be done by a licensed electrician or the homeowner

In addition, the homeowner may be required to pass some sort of test in order to be able to obtain a permit.
A homeowner can always assist an electrician - I did that with my heavy-up - saved the electrician some time/cost (he didn't have to bring in an assistant for the two-person parts of the job) but that is very much up to the electrician and YMMV.

Thank you for that info. It is an older pole garage, with limited original wiring. Some wiring-not in conduit. And one run of Romex. I just wanted to upgrade what was there, and add a few new outlets.

The intended use of the building could significantly affect the answer as well.  A "machine shed" and a "garage" may be the same size and shape, but the code requirements could be a lot different.

Wires in conduit - always OK, though some places restrict the type of conduit beyond the NEC-allowed options, and sometimes the wrong conduit is used where subject to physical damage. Wires outside conduit - never allowed. Romex (non-metallic cable) allowed indoors in most places, but some jurisdictions only allow conduit, and Romex needs to be protected from damage in certain situations as well (though that does not have to be by using conduit). But need to find out the local rules first.
